# Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005' Disk or network error.

Tags: odbc

I am receiving this error

```
Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005'

Disk or network error.

/Orig_AmStaffing/Class/APSClass.asp, line 16
```

I made it work by replacing

```
set adoUser = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")  
adoUser.Open Application("APSConnStr")
```

with

```
set adoUser = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")
adoUser.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"      
adoUser.Open "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\APS.mdb"
```

The problem now is that, there are lot of pages getting this error so I have to replace all those non-working code with the new one.

My client told me that the code is working fine until it was transferred to the new server.
So the question is, how can I make it work by using the old way of connection

```
adoUser.Open Application("APSConnStr")
```

I think I have to configure the settings on my ODBC or Computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by the help of this http://www.adopenstatic.com/experiments/ConnStringSpeed.asp

On the global.asa the directory of the access file (.mdb) was pointed on the wrong directory

```
Application ("APSConnStr") = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\AmStaffing\App_Data\APS.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
```

which is suppose to be

```
Application ("APSConnStr") = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\APS.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
```